# Is it possible to subtract two colums from two separate tables in SQL trigger?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm a student and I'm creating my simple inventory system.

I want to subtract my 2 tables `orders` and `product`.

If the order has been received the `order_quantity` should subtract to `product_quantity`...

Is it possible if I use MYSQL triggers?

Comment: Yes possible. But you should really handle this in your application code.

Comment: umm table orders(order_quantity) to product(product_quantity)?? sorry i'm bad at explaining :)

Comment: It's actually BEFORE Delete in triggers and i really don't know how to to it

Comment: Read up on Triggers manual. Ref: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/trigger-syntax.html